# web_socket_channel throwing Unsupported operation: Platform._version

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

How can I use the websocket package with dart web? I have the following code

```
import 'package:projectname/data/chat/chat_message.dart';
import 'package:projectname/data/chat/chat_provider.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

import '../path.dart';

class MockChatProvider implements ChatProvider {
  @override
  IOWebSocketChannel connect() {
    return IOWebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse(Path.joinChat));
  }

  @override
  sendChatMessage(IOWebSocketChannel channel, ChatMessage message) {
    channel.sink.add(message.toJson());
  }
}
```

But when I try to connect I get the following error

```
Unsupported operation: Platform._version
```

The package does say it supports web. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the package `package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart`
**TLDR;**
I think you should use this...

```
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';
```

...instead of...

```
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
```

and use it as

```
WebSocketChannel connect() {
...
return WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse(Path.joinChat));
...
sendChatMessage(WebSocketChannel channel, ChatMessage message) {
```

**Note:** I have not tried and tested it!

I think the problem is that you found the right package, but you're using directly `IOWebSocketChannel`. That only works on places where `dart:io` is available. There's another class in that package, `HtmlWebSocketChannel` that only works on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are importing `package:web_socket_channel/io.dart` for web and you should instead import `package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart`.

Related GitHub issue on package's repo: https://github.com/dart-lang/web_socket_channel/issues/159

Comment: Aah I see now and use WebSocketChannel instead of IOWebSocketChannel

Comment: Yes, exactly! :) 

And if you use it for other platforms then use `IOWebSocketChannel` as well and guard that with `kIsWeb` like the final comment on the issue says.

Happy coding!